# TeeChart rendering jagged fonts after extensive usage

Tags: c#, .net, charts, teechart

I'm seeing a situation when using TeeChart .NET components and a changed font, where after running for a while (~5-20 days), the charts will start rendering horribly jagged fonts. This is in a web-application built using .NET, which renders the charts to the filesystem, from where they are then later served.

After this bug has occured everything will continue to function perfectly except that the charts look horrible, until I reboot the machine. After a reboot everything looks great again, until after an undetermined amount of time (usually within 2 weeks), the problem occurs again.

The following is an illustration of a chart displaying the bug:

[Broken pie chart http://geekp.dk/teechart/ugly.png](http://geekp.dk/teechart/ugly.png)

The correct rendition of this chart, which was generated right after a reboot attempting to fix the above, is the following:

[Correct pie chart http://geekp.dk/teechart/correct.png](http://geekp.dk/teechart/correct.png)

The issue is global across charts of all types in the web and always displays for all charts once it has occured (not one at a time or such.)

The font this uses is Calibri, and it is created as follows, and after this the (System.Drawing) Font-object is used to specify the .Name and .Size of the TeeChart "ChartFont" objects.

```
Font font = new Font("Calibri", 15);
```

I don't know for a fact that the font has anything to do with this, that's just my guess.

This issue seems to affect all charts created by the machine after it occurs. I have a different web which uses default TeeChart fonts for its charts, which displayed the issue whenever it had occured. However, after moving this website off to another machine, it hasn't displayed this behavior. It still happens on the web using the special font however. This web is also the one generating the most chart-renditions (estimated 1-2 charts every 5 seconds).

Does anyone have any ideas for things to check, or have you seen similar behavior from TeeChart before?

Edit: TeeChart is version 4.0.2010.13051.

Comment: Could you please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" and let us know the exact instructions we should follow to reproduce the problem here? You can post your files at http://www.steema.net/upload. Also, which TeeChart for .NET build are you using? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet - I'm afraid I can't reproduce this problem in a simple manner. This occurs on a complex webserver running several websites, oftne after more than a week of usage. I've added version info to the original question.

Comment: It is very difficult for us addressing an issue without  being able to reproduce it. My recommendation would be to try upgrading TeeChart assembly version (current version is build 4.1.2012.09280) and check if it makes any difference. Also, if you find a consistent way to reproduce the problem please let us know.